# Different regex evaluation in collections or patterns

Tags: regex, vim

I am experiencing a strange behaviour when searching for a regular expression in vim:

I attempt to clean up superfluous whitespace in a file and want to use the substitute command for it.

When I use the following regular expression with collections, vim matches single whitespaces as well:

```
\%[\s]\{2,}
```

When I use the same regular expression with patterns instead of collections vim correctly matches only 2 or more whitespaces:

```
\%(\s\)\{2,}
```

I know that I do not need to use a collection, but if I try the expression in a online regular expression parser (e.g. [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)) it works with a collection as well.

Can anyone explain why these expression are not evaluated in the same way?

Comment: `\{2,}` part is wrong. If you escape `{` it can not be a range

Comment: Provide input string and expected output string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `\%[...]` and `\%(...\)` are completely different patterns.

- `\%[...]` means a sequence of optional atoms.
  For example, `r\%[ead]` matches "read", "rea", "re" and "r".
- While `\%(...\)` treats the enclosed atoms as a single atom.
  For example, `r\%(ead\)` matches only "read".

So that,

- `\%[\s]\{2,}` can be interpreted as `\(\s\|\)\{2,}`, then `\(\s\|\)\(\s\|\)\|\(\s\|\)\(\s\|\)\(\s\|\)\|...`.
  Here `\(\s\|\)\(\s\|\)`, the minimum pattern, can be interpreted as `\(\)\(\)`, `\(\)\(\s\)`, `\(\s\)\(\)` or `\(\s\)\(\s\)`.
  It matches 1 whitespace character too.
- `\%(\s\)\{2,}` can be interpreted as `\s\{2,}`, then `\s\s\|\s\s\s\|...`.
  It matches only 2 or more whitespace characters.

Comment: Since `\%[\s]` can match zero characters, `\%[\s]\{2,}` should match zero characters too, but it does't match so.  While `\%[\s]\%[\s]\+` match zero characters.  This difference might be a problem inside the regular expression engine of Vim.

Comment: One more note: There are many dialects for "regular expressions".  Rubular is a tool for Ruby's regular expressions, but it's not for Vim's regular expressions.

Comment: I accepted your answer now, because you go into a bit more detail than the vim docs - thanks for that, it makes a lot more sense now :)

Comment: @KanaNatsuno i figure they avoided trivial (e.g. zero character) matches for practical purposes. But by following the definition exactly, it should match zero character.

Answer (score 3):

does this answer your question?

`http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\%[]`

```
    A sequence of optionally matched atoms.  This always matches.

    It matches as much of the list of atoms it contains as possible.  
    Thus it stops at the first atom that doesnt match.  
    For example:

    /r\%[ead]

    matches "r", "re", "rea" or "read".  The longest that matches is used.
```

The problem is it **always match** and override the quantifier `{2,}` at the back.

it is rarely used, but interesting nevertheless.

Comment: I read the docs but I did not think that the "always matches" part would simply overwrite the quantifier - seems I was wrong.